# textbox customize in XML / VML

Tags: php, xml, ms-word, vml, phpdocx

Hi  i am creating a word document using PHPDOCX below code creates a textbox but i have problem customizing its style. If i just can post a picture i can show what my problem is.  Below codes create a three textbox my problem is the last text inside a text box has an extra padding bottom so it looks like the textbox has an extra empty space at the bottom. Second problem is each textbox has a big space at between them i wish i can remove it using margin-bottom. And last how can i set the font-size of the text inside the textbox.

Updated with picture hope i can get help now

```
$array = array('Drop Units OCAP'
                ,'Drop Units Details: Drop units inside carriers'
                ,'Drop Units Details: Drop units inside carriers Drop Units Details: Drop units inside carriers');




foreach($array as $value){

    $wordML = '<w:p><w:r><w:pict>
                  <v:shape  type="#_x0000_t202" 
                  style="position:absolute; z-index:99999999; width: 590;    " 
                  fillcolor = "#94BDDA;" strokecolor="none; ">

                      <v:textbox  style="mso-fit-shape-to-text:t; " inset="5pt,0pt,0pt,0pt" >
                        <w:txbxContent>
                           <w:p>
                              <w:r>
                                <w:t> '.$value.'
                                </w:t>
                              </w:r>
                            </w:p>
                        </w:txbxContent>
                      </v:textbox>
                      <w10:wrap type="square"/>
                  </v:shape>
                </w:pict></w:r></w:p>';

    $docx->addWordML($wordML);
}

$docx->createDocx('example_addTextBox_1');
```

[image]